# Google Drive V2 Java API - Upload file to specific folder

Tags: google-drive-api

Following is the method adopted to upload file to specific folder using Gdrive V2 sdk.
1) insert file to root folder (Drive.Files.insert(File,AbstractInputStream)
2) Delete the root parent reference of the new uploaded file
3) Add the specific target folder as the new parent reference to the file.

The above works.
But, if network is slow, we see the file sitting at the Root folder for quite some time before it moves to the specific target folder. How can we avoid this? Can we batch all the above three operations? But AFAIK, batching is supported for operations of a particular type like..we can batch only all Files operations or Parent operations or Revision operations. Can we batch operations belonging to different types, for example (Files.insert() and Parent.delete())?

Inputs will be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create file in specified folder directly by setting parents field in metadata.

```
{
  "title" : "test.jpg",
  "mimeType" : "image/jpeg",
  "parents": [{
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": "<folderId>"
  }]
}
```

This is what I am doing in python, but I believe there is a relevant in java.

Comment: Thanks Eric! This does work now, we had tried this earlier and it did not work then. That's why had to resort to the three step procedure.

Answer (score 1):

As eric.f mentioned in his answer, you need to set the **parent** for the **file**.

From https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

```
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Insert new file.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param title Title of the file to insert, including the extension.
   * @param description Description of the file to insert.
   * @param parentId Optional parent folder's ID.
   * @param mimeType MIME type of the file to insert.
   * @param filename Filename of the file to insert.
   * @return Inserted file metadata if successful, {@code null} otherwise.
   */
  private static File insertFile(Drive service, String title, String description,
      String parentId, String mimeType, String filename) {
    // File's metadata.
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(title);
    body.setDescription(description);
    body.setMimeType(mimeType);

    // Set the parent folder.
    if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
      body.setParents(
          Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
    }

    // File's content.
    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);
    try {
      File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

      // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
      // System.out.println("File ID: %s" + file.getId());

      return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```