# Upload local file into Google drive from java

Tags: java, gradle, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a local text file into drive from java and gradle. I keep on getting the following errors.

1. cannot find symbol import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentReference;
2. error: cannot find symbol body.setTitle("My File Title");
3. cannot find symbol Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
4. cannot find symbol File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

Seems to be a import error but I am using gradle 2.3 so don't know how's that possible.

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import  com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp ;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;

import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.drive.*;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentReference;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DriveQuickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Drive API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/drive-java-quickstart.json");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

/** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 *
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
 * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart.json
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
    Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @return an authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
        DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}

/**
 * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
 * @return an authorized Drive client service
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Drive.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    Drive service = getDriveService();
 // File's metadata.
File body = new File();
body.setTitle("My File Title");
body.setDescription("My File Description");
body.setMimeType("text/plain");

String parentId = "ParentDir";

// Set the parent folder.
if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
  body.setParents(
      Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
}

String filename = "Resources/myfile.txt";


java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("text/plain", fileContent);
try {
  File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();

  System.out.println("Inserted File ID: " + file.getId());

} catch (IOException e) {

  System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);

}
}



 }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235399/upload-file-into-google-drive-using-java-api?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338837/google-drive-v2-java-api-upload-file-to-specific-folder ?

Comment: @Srikanta I had already gone through the above links before posting the query here...It is not related my query!!

Comment: What IDE are you using if any? Can you run `gradle dependencies` from the command line and ensure the required dependencies are being downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are using v2 Google Drive API code but you are including the v3 gradle/ jar files or vice versa, because the only functions that it is giving error is insert, setType ...which has changed in version 3 to create, setName...